# How to display current SVN branch in Intellij IDEA title?

Tags: intellij-idea

I switch to different SVN branches quite often, usually I use 1 branch for 1 issue I'm working on.

IDEA 12 doesn't show current SVN branch in some good visible area, and sometimes I forget what branch I'm working on, and have to go to Changes -> Working copy info -> Refresh

Is there a way to show current branch in a window title or in a status bar (as IDEA does for git)?

I'm also trying to write a plugin that can show current SVN branch in IDEA title, but don't really want to read tons of APIs and documentation.

As I understand, if there is no standard way, I need to:
1) Somehow subscribe to SVN Update event
2) Modify IDEA title (or status bar) and add current branch name to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not supported yet, please [vote for this open request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80019) to get this feature implemented sooner.

Comment: I couldn't find or there is no voting system in the bug tracker... ?

Answer (score 9):

I simply hit the 'Update Project (Ctrl+T)' to identify branch. In a 'Use branch' field it will show current branch.

But of course it's not as convinient as to have some status bar for branch or something like this. Sometimes I forget to switch between branches and I think that if there will be such bar then it may solve this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for some automated way to do this.  Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for that.  But the way I solve this problem is by manually writing the branch name in the project title.  For example, I've got one project named `Product Trunk` and another project named `Product Branch v2.3`.

Comment: Yeah, it means I have to manually rename my project after each switch, which leaves the original problem - sometimes I can forget to change it.

Comment: It may have something to do with how SVN doesn't really have branches in the same way that git does. Sure, its not hard to do but it relies on conventions in SVN as opposed to first class support in git. But I came to this question because I was looking for the same thing as I use svn switch to move between branches...

Answer (score 0):

There is another Request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76042 - this one got more attention, so please vote for this one too.